# Redirecting to specific page in FB app with apprequests API

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, apprequests

I have a FaceBook app in which I use the [`apprequests` API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) to invite friends to my app. Now, when the user receives my invitation, they're redirected to the first page in my app.

How can I redirect them to a specific page in my app?

This is what my `apprequests` looks like:

```
function newInvite(){
    var msg = document.getElementById('msg_look_id').value;

    var receiverUserIds = FB.ui({ 
        method : 'apprequests',
        message: msg,
        title: "Select friends to send ",
    }, function(response) {
        alert("IDS : " + response.request_ids);
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried window.location.href?

Comment: i didn't meant in the app itself , i meant when users getting the invention in the notifications and then press to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when a user comes to your app, you get their FacebookId, correct?  When a user comes, check your database for that ID and if it is not there, add it and then redirect them to the page you want to show "new" users.  If they're already in your database, then leave them on your normal home page.

Comment: Thanks ! i already have the id detection mechanism so i just need to use it you say ...